# Phoenix app on production is crashing and not in dev

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a Phoenix app that is on production right now but I noticed that whenever an error happens it just straight up crash the whole app while in development it doesn't. First I tried to fill all the errors but then I thought that that's not how Elixir/Erlang works, tried in development with the same operation and the error  is only logged once and the crashed Tasks are restarted meanwhile in prod it logs the same error several times and crashes the whole app. I'm not sure if it's something with my config, this is the `Endpoint` config I have for prod right now.

```
config :appname, AppName.Web.Endpoint,
  on_init: {AppName.Web.Endpoint, :load_from_system_env, []},
  cache_static_manifest: "priv/static/cache_manifest.json",
  http: [port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  url: [host: "localhost", port: {:system, "PORT"}],
  root: ".",
  debug_errors: false,
  server: true,
  code_reloader: false,
  check_origin: false,
  version: Mix.Project.config[:version],
  secret_key_base: System.get_env("SECRET_KEY_BASE"),
  watchers: []
```

And this is the `dev.exs` file

```
config :appname, AppName.Web.Endpoint,
  http: [port: 4000],
  debug_errors: true,
  code_reloader: true,
  check_origin: false,
  secret_key_base: "rFiGCabqtoBaPZUZLoGaRuhgbBkynQazMnI2dpxN4aQEJzyQx0J7beyU2AZ0yMYO",
  watchers: [node: ["node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch", "watch", "--stdin",
                    cd: Path.expand("../assets", __DIR__)]]
```

I hope it has something to do with config, It's kinda annoying having to be restarting the app for minimal errors that should be just avoided.

EDIT: I just noticed that the app sometimes crash and sometimes it doesn't, I was logging the events of the terminal and saw this:

```
(Postgrex.Error) ERROR 22001 (string_data_right_truncation): value too long for type character varying(255)
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:571: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.struct/7
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:467: Ecto.Repo.Schema.apply/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/repo/schema.ex:276: anonymous fn/13 in Ecto.Repo.Schema.do_update/4
    (euridime) lib/euridime/telegram/handlers/keyboard/keyboard.ex:331: Euridime.Keyboard.set_user_wallet/2
    (euridime) lib/euridime/telegram/handlers/keyboard/keyboard.ex:136: Euridime.Keyboard.check_command/1
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:645: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:645: Enum.each/2
    (euridime) lib/euridime/telegram/task.ex:9: Euridime.Task.pull_updates/1
Function: &Euridime.Task.pull_updates/0
    Args: []
```

P.S. This is just the error that crashed it last time, being Postgres related, it crashes for other reasons too.

This is the error logged many times, sometimes it is just logged once and avoided, then why does it crash here instead of being restarted? I'm thinking that it just gets restarted too many times then proceeds to crash? How could I avoid this?

EDIT 2: start callback:

```
def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec

    # Define workers and child supervisors to be supervised
    children = [
      # Start the Ecto repository
      supervisor(Euridime.Repo, []),
      # Start the endpoint when the application starts
      supervisor(Euridime.Web.Endpoint, []),

      worker(Task, [Euridime.Task, :pull_updates, []], id: :pull_updates),
      worker(Euridime.DETS, []),
      worker(Euridime.Emailer, []),
    ]

    # Registry
    gen = [
      worker(Euridime.Server, []),
      worker(Euridime.Notify, [], restart: :transient),
      worker(Euridime.PayService, [], restart: :transient)
    ]
    supervise(gen, strategy: :simple_one_for_one)

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: Euridime.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
```

Comment: Please show us the application `start` callback and the supervision tree.

Comment: @mudasobwa updated.

Comment: Seems fine. How do you start the application?

Comment: @mudasobwa I'm using `MIX_ENV=prod <some variables (PORT, etc)> iex -S mix phx.server` I wanted to create a release but had some problems regarding OS and incompatibilities and I didn't have the time to fix them.

Comment: OK, first of all, why do you supervise `gen` with `:simple_one_for_one` strategy? It requires exactly one child and is usually used to dynamically create children. Please change it to `:one_for_one` in the first place (this will unlikely solve the whole issue, though it can.)

Comment: solving the problem via the supervision tree is sure one way - but what stands out for me here is: ```value too long for type character varying``` it seems that you either have a wrong field type or you are saving to much chars inside the varchar

Comment: @mudasobwa you're right, but I do need to dynamically start some process on the Server module, so can I supervise that module using `:simple_one_for_one` and `:one_for_one` for the others?

Comment: @Pfitz Yes, but this time it was this error, it has crashed for other things too, for example using `String.to_integer/1` on a `nil` value has crashed the app.

Comment: “can I supervise that module using [...]”—sure thing; the strategy is the property of _supervised_ worker.

Comment: @mudasobwa Ah, I think the issue is that I had `:one_for_one` instead of `:one_for_all` on the `child` list for `Supervisor.start_link/2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I had some bad strategies on the Supervision Tree, I had `:one_for_one` instead of `:one_for_all` which was causing crashes, I'm not sure about the technical explanation about what processes needed to be restarted in order for the app not to crash. It's solved for now, I'll need to keep testing this behaviour on production to check.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to increase your `max_restarts` and `max_seconds`. By default these are 3 and 5 respectively. This means the supervisor will restart the child process a maximum of 3 times within 5 seconds - if your child crashes a 4th time within 5 seconds, the supervisor will not restart the child process.

See https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Supervisor.html for details.